# Warning for new local repository updates?

Tags: centos, yum, repository

I've installed a YUM local repository on CentOS 7.4 and all works well, clients updates successfully.

I only have to warn myself when a new update appears on official mirror. I've tried

```
lftp -e 'open http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages \
&& lcd /path/ \
&& mirror -n --delete \
&& exit'
```

to download new packets, but always goes and brings some packets I've already downloaded before.

I don't know if it doesn't matter and when I run the command

```
createrepo --update
```

it updates disposing apart the repeated packets.

Is there a way to look for only the packets that are't present on local repository?

Answer (score 1):

I would use an rsync mirror. `rsync` will only pull down files you don't have.

```
rsync -avz --exclude='repo*' rsync://mirror.cisp.com/CentOS/7/updates/x86_64/ /var/www/html/repos/centos/7/updates/x86_64/
createrepo --update /var/www/html/repos/centos/7/updates/x86_64/
```

[Here is a really good article](https://deviant.engineer/2016/03/repo-centos7/) on creating an rsync mirror of a CentOS repository and which has detailed instructions.